# "Go To File" Feature/Plugin for Notepad++

Tags: plugins, notepad++

Is there a way to get the *Go to file...* functionality from Textmate in Notepad++?

For example, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>, a dialog box comes up, type in (partial) string and it filters through the files in the project.

Or is there a Project Manager plugin that includes this feature?

Comment: I found what I was looking for, there's a plugin called Open File in Solution, but it takes a little bit of tweaking to get working properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plugin that I found that has this feature is called Open File in Solution

Here's a link to download the plugin and documentation:
http://npp.incrediblejunior.com/

Using the Notepad++ Plugin Manager, you can download the plugin directly from there (and it'll download the dependencies: SolutionHub and SolutionHub UI)

Before you can use the plugin however, you need to do some setup in SolutionHub UI which is detailed at the link above.

Then you can create a new Shortcut mapping to bind the plugin to a key.

I've been using it for the past few hours, it's really fast. Happy I found this.

Answer (score 28):

Try File Switcher plugin for Notepad++, you can download it directly from the Plugin manager. Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then search your file name.

Comment: This is a great plugin. I wonder if there is another that can also list files to jump to with text you are looking for.

Comment: Press `Ctrl+Shift+O`, then type the file name or use arrow. Additionally have switched Print (Ctrl+P) and File Switcher (Ctrl+Shift+O) commands. After that change, similar to `VS Code`, `Ctrl+P` goes to `File Switcher` to go to a file in Notepad++ too.

Comment: it's named `FileFinder`now

Answer (score 6):

I found "Navigate To" plugin from plugin manager and it's working perfect for this need. Hope this helps to someone.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: Yes it is. But I guess ability navigate to file in the workspace can be bit more helpful.

Comment: An advantage to the "Navigate To" plugin, at least in my case, is it was already showing under "Available" in my "Plugins Admin" panel, so was easy to install. Also easy to use (shortcut `ctl` + `,`).

Comment: I usually have about dozens of files open. This plugin is always one of the first plugins to install in a new windows system.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a simple plugin for Notepad++ in Delphi 7 for this purpose, because I was disappointed by the ones that already exists. I think you will find it useful.

I named it "Open File In Folders". It's latest version is 1.02. Here is a screenshot of the main window of the plugin:

[NPP plugins menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRNwO.gif)

You can get it from GitHub here: https://github.com/meboev/NppOpenFileInFolders

## Installation

If you do not want to compile it, just download the OpenFileInFolders.dll and place it in your C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins folder. Then restart Notepad++.

## Features

- Saves its configuration into the Window Registry
- The selected text from NPP is automatically populated into the search field. You can use it for quickly finding imports, requires, etc...
- You can select multiple folders to search from. Useful if your project is in multiple drives (c:, d:)
- You can exclude case insensitively strings, pipe delimited (\node_modules\|.git) from the results
- You can see/copy the full path of all the files you are searching into.
- You can limit the results to a predefined values, to speed up the search for big projects
- You can open the results directly inside a Windows Explorer window

Comment: can you search/go to files with a specific text as well?